# Join with multiple columns from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables. First table is named **price_changes** where as the other is named as **area**. The structure of **price_changes** is :

```
**listing_id**  **old_price** **new_price** **change_date**
240509            180999        100234        2016-03-30
230599            165789        189760        2017-06-12
245678            123456        176432        2016-12-08
```

here the **listing_id**,**old_price**,**new_price** are integers whereas **change_date** is in text.

The next table which is **area** has a structure like this:

```
**listing_id** **built_area**, **used_area** 
240509           340             0
230599           0               789
245678           125             175
```

here the **listing_id**, **built_area**, **used_area** are all integer values.

The Sql query that I want to make and unable do so is this:

calculate the average square meter price of properties with an increased price in 2016 that have built up or used area > 200. Here the average square meter price would mean summing both **built_area** and **used_area** to form a new column called **total_area** and for price I have to use the **increased_price** column.

I tried to do it with nested Queries but was not successful. The nested query that I came up was

SELECT listing_id  FROM fast_course_reg.`price changes` where new_price > old_price and change_date 
like '2016%' and listing_id in 
(select listing_id from area where built_area > 200 or used_area > 200);

but the problem is nested query doesn't allow to add more than one column in the nested section. With Join, I don't know how do to that since inner join doesn't allow to select multiple columns from both tables.

Comment: Edit your question and show the attempts you have made.

Answer (score 1):

To get the properties whose price increased in 2016:

```
select listing_id, max(new_price)
from price_changes
where old_price < new_price and change_date >= '2016-01-01' and
      change_date < '2017-01-01'
group by listing_id;
```

You can then use this as a subquery to get the averages.  The result is something like this:

```
select sum(new_price) / sum(built_area + used_area)
from (select listing_id, max(new_price) as new_price
      from price_changes
      where old_price < new_price and change_date >= '2016-01-01' and
            change_date < '2017-01-01'
      group by listing_id
     ) l join
     area a
     using (listing_id)
where built_area > 200 or used_area > 200;
```